# iphone @selector has two argument

Tags: iphone, selector

I have a method like this:

```
-(void)A:(int)a B:(int)b{    
}
```

and want to put the method into a new thread:

```
NSInvocationOperation *theOp = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(A:B:) object:nil];
```

but "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple's docs: "The selector to invoke when running the operation. The selector may take 0 or 1 parameters;". So if you want to call a method with more parameters, create an extra method with a single parameter and call the method with more parameters from there.

Answer (score 3):

The method you invoke with `NSInvocationOperation` can only take a single parameter, and that parameter must be an Objective-C object (like `NSNumber`) and not a plain C type (like `int`).

Typically, to handle multiple parameters you use an NSDictionary or NSArray to hold the parameters:

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSDictionary*)parameters 
{
    int a = [[parameters objectForKey:@"A"] intValue];
    int b = [[parameters objectForKey:@"B"] intValue];

    // do something with a and b
}


[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self
          selector:@selector(myMethod:)
            object:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:123], @"A",
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:456], @"B",
                     nil]];
```

Alternatively, you can use an `NSInvocation` object to invoke your method.  This allows any number and any type of parameters, but it's typically much easier to just put your parameters in an NSDictionary than to construct an NSInvocation object.

[Information on how to use NSInvocation.](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/construct-nsinvocation-for-any-message.html)

Answer (score 1):

If possible, try to have one array or dictionary as the parameter to the selector.
Then when you are invoking convert your two params into one object (either array or dictionary) and send that object.
In the selector, i think you can get them back from array or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second B:

usuage would be:

```
[[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(A:) object:nil];
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance (and psuedo-hijacking), but wouldn't that call a different method from the original? How would that work?